# Can Git be used to manage both debug and release versions of an app

Tags: git

Android Studio allows you to configure your project to create both a debug and release version of your app. It also allows you to create "flavors" of an app, which is essentially compiling in different features (trial version, full version, etc).

I question whether using this is necessary if using Git would accomplish the same thing. With Git, you can create branches that effectively allow you to create "feature" versions. However, I am not entirely convinced Git would allow you to easily switch between a debug and release version. You can create a "debug" and "release" branch and just switch between the two, but these branches always remain apart until you merge them. Sometimes, the only difference between a debug and release version of an app is just the project settings which might include keys in your app, or resources that are only used when testing locally. So my question is whether Git can be used in an easy way to handle both a debug and release version of an app.

Comment: If you use rebase you replay your changes in a branch on top of the changes from a , for example, master branch or feature branch. You can then easily keep specific "debug" changes on one branch but all else on a common branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Git branching system is very powerful. However, in my opinion it is not adapted to manage Debug and Realease configurations of a project.

Indeed, 2 branches of the same repository correspond to 2 different states of your project. You can create a new branch to implement a new feature, fix a specific bug, etc. and merge later. You can also create a branch to manage a different configuration of your project (debug/release), but if you do that, you will have to duplicate almost all your commits into these 2 branches. The 'git cherry-pick' command helps you to copy a commit from a branch to another, but you will often have to reset and amend a commit to fix some debug/release specific lines.

I'm not comfortable with development of Android applications, but I'm pretty sure Git will not be your best option to have a efficient management of your debug and release configurations.

Comment: Having used Git for a while now, I think you are right. It seems strange though that Git doesn't have some mechanism in place that allows you to easily switch between a debug and release version. Personally I think Git should include a feature that supports this as it belongs to versioning as well.

Comment: @AndroidDev: why shall a version control system provide support for build configurations? Every serious build environment handles build configurations independent of version control.

Comment: @eckes Because build configurations is intrinsic to version control.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have mainly config files that are changing between branches and not all the code, I think that you could use Git's [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) which could allow you to "link" a repository with the source code to a folder like /src of your main repository (the one with the two debug/release branches). You would have to work with two repositories but maybe it is cleaner. Also, this is only really useful if you have to change frequently the config files of the two versions...

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tools for the right task.

If you have a DEBUG and a RELEASE configuration for your product, this should be handled by your **build environment**, not by your source code management.

For example, in Visual Studio, you have at least two build configurations: Debug and Release. These configurations are contained in ONE project file/solution. Upon build, you decide which configuration to build: Debug or Release.

Same would go for working with Makefiles: if you want to have a DEBUG and a RELEASE build, you need to have a `DEBUG` target and a `RELEASE` target contained in your `Makefile`. Which target to build is decided for each build and has nothing to do with version control, branching or whatever.

This is also important for portability: if you decide to switch from Git to another version control system one day, do you really want to have your build configurations managed by your version control? This would add additional efforts that are completely un-needed.

Let your build system handle the build system stuff and let your version control do versioning stuff.

Comment: Sorry, but the building of debug/release using Visual Studio is an outdated way of building stuff. That model existed long before Git came along. Same with Make. Build configurations is actually part of the version control, at least as far as current development models is concerned.

Comment: @AndroidDev: do you have any documentation about your state-of-the-art way of "building stuff"? I'd be quite curious.